# What is the go-to way of configuring PHP with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I've heard many good things about Nginx lately, and I wanted to put it on my slicehost server. I am in a fix for ram, and would like to get Wordpress and wp-super-cache configured. I was just wondering the 'recommended way' of get PHP setup, because I see so many webpages saying their way is correct.

No compiling if possible please, it makes updating a drag D=

Answer (score 1):

Does the Nginx wiki page for setting up PHP with FastCGI fail to cover your needs?

http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample